# Always same result in JSTL <c:when> tag

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I got this weird issue with my login.jsp page. Lets take a look a part of jsp codes in here:

```
<%
  String userName = "";
  String password = "";
  boolean login;

  //mysql stuffs are in here

if(resultSet.next()) {
  login = true;
  out.println("It is true.");
} else {
  login = false;
  out.println("It is false.");
%>
```

I get `It is true` output top of the page when I login with correct username/password and I get `It is false` output with some wrong login info.

Everything is working fine untill this point. Now, lets see the html stuffs in here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${login}">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Page content in here with success -->
        </div>
      </c:when>

      <c:otherwise>
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Page content in here with error -->
        </div>
      </c:otherwise>
    <c:choose>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I always get the same HTML page content regardless I type right or wrong loing info but I always get the correct output from boolean at the top of the page. Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: What is the relationship between these two pieces of code? Are you actually mixing scriptlets with JSTL in the same page or what?

Comment: Everything you see here is in a "login.jsp" file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing scriptlets (`<%...%>`) with JSTL defeats the purpose of using JSTL. Also, variables set in scriptlets cannot be accessed in JSTL with `${}`.  JSTL is meant to replace `<%...%>` stuff and to work with an MVC approach where you use a Servlet as a controller. The stuff you have in `<%...%>` should be in a Servlet that sets a request attribute and forwards to the jsp which contains the JSTL.  Then JSTL can read the request attribute with `${login}`.

So, inside login.java, your servlet, after the code that sets the value of the boolean (inside your doPost method):

```
request.setAttribute("login", login);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
return;
```

You would put the JSP under WEB-INF to prevent any user from going to it directly. Instead you will have them go to the URL of the login servlet, which will control access to the JSP, for which reason it is called a "controller."  (You can see the [servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for more info on this.)

You'll also want to set no-cache headers to prevent pages secured behind a login from being cached since those pages being cached would present a security risk by allowing anyone with physical access to the machine to see what the user saw when logged in after they have logged out.

Comment: In the index.jsp file's login form, do I need change action=login.jsp to action="loginController.java"?

Comment: @oxyt, You would map the loginController.java to a URL in your web.xml and set the action of the form to that url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got just one small issue left. Before remove <% .. %> and use controller class, I had this code working:

`<jsp:useBean id="userBean" class="org.simpleservlet.User" scope="session" />` and
`<title>Welcome <jsp:getProperty name="userBean" property="username"/></title>`

But now i get `null` instead of username in the title.

Comment: @oxyt, `jsp:useBean` doesn't work with servlets, so you have to get rid of `jsp:useBean` and put the bean into the session in a servlet with `session.setAttribute("userBean", userBean);` and then print it in JSTL with `<c:out value="${userBean.username}"/>` or just `${userBean.username}`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133956/passing-java-bean-properties-to-jstl

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a "page scope" variable in order to use it between ${ ... }

Change your example at the top to:

```
if(resultSet.next()) {
    pageContext.setAttribute("login", "true");
    out.println("It is true.");
} else {
    pageContext.setAttribute("login", "false");
    out.println("It is false.");
}
```

And it should all work.

Note:  This assumes you don't really need the "boolean login" anywhere else within <% ... %>   You can also get rid of the "boolean login" line, if that's the case.  If you do need it, then leave that in and add the "login = true" and "login = false" lines back in, but you still need the pageContext.setAttribute statements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well @alfreema. This is working without any problem but to use a seperate controller seems to be a better way to go, imho. You guyz rock! :)

Comment: It definitely is the better way to go.